# How to divide and get the percentage of the value of two different textboxes in userform?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

i'm new with VBA and i'm currently working on creating an evaluation form for one of our LOBs. I'm having a hard  time understanding what is wrong with my current code wherein it would not divide the value of two text boxes. when i tried to divide the value of one text box to a number it would work. however that is not what i'm looking for since the value in the text boxes are dependent on the form questions (there are questions that are NA).

I have tried the code below and its not working.

```
Sub CusImp2_div()

CusImp2.Value = Val(CusImp1.Value) / Val(CusImp3.Value)
CusImp2.Value = Format(Me.CusImp2.Value, "0.00%")

End Sub

the source of the values are...

Sub custotal_mulcal()

Me.CusImp1.Value = Val(CustTotal1.Value) * (0.33)

Me.CusImp1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(Val(CusImp1.Value), 2)

Me.CusImp3.Value = Val(CustTotal2.Value) * (0.33)

Me.CusImp3.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(Val(CusImp3.Value), 2)
End Sub
```

when i run the formula and activate the userform i'm experiencing a debug problem and i can't seem to figure out what to do.

i expect the output to be a percentage of the output ex. 96%

i really hope that someone can help me with this and i'm actually frustrated because im runnning after a deadline.

thank you!

Comment: Does "it's not working" mean that you are getting an error? What is the error and on what line?

Comment: Hi. Im getting an error on CusImp2.Value = Val(CusImp1.Value) / Val(CusImp3.Value) i try to go over and over it but i dont getvwhy im getting the error

Comment: What is the error you're getting, and what are the values of CusImp1 and CusImp3 when that happens?

Comment: @Stacy771991 are those sub into the userform or in the module ?

Comment: Hi. The sub is for the userform. The value of CusImp1 is the total of the scores in one criticality and CusImp1 is the value of the total available points in that criticality. There are some questions that would sometimes get an NA and the formula should also be flexible.

Comment: the error that I'm getting when I run the code is "Run-time error '11': Division by zero"

Comment: If CusImp3 could have a value of zero then you will need to test for that *before* trying to perform the division, or you will get the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

'I think I found the answer to this question. I found the formula below in Youtube and the form is working well now. The only limitation though is that the percentage would not change even though I tried to change my answers (I will look into how I can work around this one)..

```
Sub CusImp2_div()

Dim a As Double
Dim b As Double
Dim answer As Double

a = CusImp1.Value
b = CusImp3.Value
answer = a / b

If b <> 0 Then
answer = a / b

End If

Me.CusImp2.Value = answer

Me.CusImp2.Value = Format(Me.CusImp2.Value, "0.00%")

End Sub
```